# How do I kickoff workflow after new document added to library?

Tags: workflow, document-library, designer-workflow

I've created a workflow for a library. I have it associated as I can see in SharePoint Designer. How to I set the workflow to trigger automatically and begin the workflow once a document is added. I'm only using SharePoint designer, so no code please, or at least how would I do it in Designer not Visual Studio.

I don't want Manual Start, want Auto-start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options for the workflow, you simple set it to start when an item is added to the library under Start Options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much John! It's just simple things that sometimes throw yah.